# Save Array Values Column wise to CSV file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

Trying to save my Array values to CSV file column wise using javascript. Right now my code saves the array values row wise.

Current Output -

- country1,country2,country3,country4
- capital1,capital2,capital3,capital4,
- currency1,currency2,currency3,currency4

Required Output -

- country1,capital1,currency1
- country2,capital2,currency2
- country3,capital3,currency3
- country4,capital4,currency4

My code so far -

```
<form>
    <input id="download" type="button" value="Download">
</form>

function downloadableCSV(rows) {
  var content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

  rows.forEach(function(column, index) {
   content = content + column.join(",") + "\n";
  });

  return encodeURI(content);
}

var country = ["England","Australia","Mexico","Brazil","Spain","Portugal","Italy","Thailand","Japan"];
var capital = ["London","Canberra","Mexico City","Brasilia","Madrid","Lisbon","Rome","Bangkok","Tokyo"];
var currency = ["Pound","Dollar","peso","Brazilian real","Euro","Euro","Euro","Thai baht","Japanese yen"];
var continent = ["Europe","Australia","NorthAmerica","SouthAmerica","Europe","Europe","Europe","Asia","Asia"];
var language = ["English","English","Spanish","Portuguese","Spainish","Portuguese","Italian","Thailand","Japanese"];
var heading =  ["Country","Capital","currency","continent","language"];

var rows = [[heading],[country],[capital],[currency],[continent],[language]];

$("#download").click(function() {
  window.open(downloadableCSV(rows));
});
```

I tried using various functions before but was unsuccessful.Is there a way to implement the required output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To group your data you can use `zip` from lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zip)

Here is working js code (https://jsbin.com/ditodosime/edit?html,js,output):

```
function downloadableCSV(heading, rows) {
  var content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

  var dataRows = rows.map(function(columnValues, index) {
    return columnValues.join(",");
  });

  content += heading + "\n" + dataRows.join("\n");

  return encodeURI(content);
}

var country = ["England","Australia","Mexico","Brazil","Spain","Portugal","Italy","Thailand","Japan"];
var capital = ["London","Canberra","Mexico City","Brasilia","Madrid","Lisbon","Rome","Bangkok","Tokyo"];
var currency = ["Pound","Dollar","peso","Brazilian real","Euro","Euro","Euro","Thai baht","Japanese yen"];
var continent = ["Europe","Australia","NorthAmerica","SouthAmerica","Europe","Europe","Europe","Asia","Asia"];
var language = ["English","English","Spanish","Portuguese","Spainish","Portuguese","Italian","Thailand","Japanese"];
var heading =  ["Country","Capital","currency","continent","language"];

var rows = _.zip(country,capital,currency,continent,language);

window.open(downloadableCSV(heading,  rows));
```